# How to leverage reputation systems of other communities to encourage participation in your own

Tags: gamification

I am developing a community from scratch whose target audience typically frequents several other communities and utilizes different collaboration tools, each of which has its own activity or reputation profile.

My goal for my community is to encourage cross community collaboration, which to me seems like I should leverage the reputation and activity profiles of these different tools, rather than only create a separate gamification system.

Are there good examples out there of communities that do leverage reputation or gamification systems of established third party communities.  How would one develop a community platform feature that would implement such a capability?

Specifically in my case: I'm working on developing a professional community that links multiple open source software development projects.  Each of these projects has its own collaboration mechanism. Like many projects, they use a combination of GitHub, Jira, Stack Overflow for primary collaboration. A mix of forum or newsgroup software is used - anything from Google Groups to mail list managers.

**What is a way to allow my community members to show and add to their professional reputation in these other established communities?**

[Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/) is somewhat close to to the experience I'm looking for. What I like is that it allows you to link your GitHub profile, where contributors to open source software projects have their statistics and contributions displayed. It also allows one to connect LinkedIn and Twitter. The former adds some professional reputation, and the latter is just social media.
What it lacks is a connection to Stack Overflow, which is also an important reputation source for engineers.
However this is less a "community profile" or service, and more of a recruitment oriented social site for developers.

@zerotime suggested [Geeklist](https://geekli.st/home) or [Masterbranch](https://masterbranch.com/).
Masterbrach is closest in terms of linking multiple communities together in a conglomerate reputation. However that seems to be where they end - making the composite profile.  I'm looking for examples who's using a capability like this to drive engagement across multiple communities.

Comment: Do you look for a software linking this stuff together?  [Geeklist](https://geekli.st/home) or [Masterbranch](https://masterbranch.com/) could be some ideas. I still have no clue what exactly you want to have. Are these two approaches steps into the right direction, or do you look for something more specific?

Comment: I am looking for other examples of this approach I'm considering.  Based on that, then there is a question of whether I can buy software, or have to build it.

Comment: BTW, thanks for those two suggestions.  I had forgotten about Geeklist, and didn't know about Masterbranch.  Looks like the Masterbranch is trying to compete with Coderwall. While I have a different goal, Masterbranch might be closest in the kind approach I'm seeeking.

Comment: So I looked up different websites like this [one](http://www.appvita.com/2012/12/25/coderwall-build-your-reputation-as-a-coder/). However, it seems like the pieces of software I suggested are the only ones out there. So, what do you want to know? How you should build up your own software? Do you want to use the reputation won on your site to encourage users to post on other sites? Your post is really confusing for me. Did you not answer your question by saying that these pieces of software can't be used and you are figuratively forced to build your own? I simply don't get it right now. Sorry.

Comment: Zerotime - Much due to your excellent research, the answer may very well be "build your own."  I wonder if it's really even possible in a seamless way.  The three we've found only do it for purposes of attracting a community, not really linking together multiple communities.

Answer (score 3):

The only answer I can think of is Klout's effort to integrate reputations across social platforms.  Lithium bought them recently and is integrating it into their existing community platform, although so far that just means you can see someone's Klout score on their profile.

edit: So Klout has been around for a while. They attempt to merge all of your scores on various social platforms, such as LinkedIn, Twitter, Facebook, etc. They give you one single number which determines their estimation of your reach and influence. To you as a consumer, you'll get "perks" from vendors who want you to mention their products online, hopefully. Lithium bought them a couple years ago and is incorporating the Klout score into their community platform and social monitoring tool. They're also hoping to expand Klout to products as a centralized review tool like Bazarrevoice

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained what Klout's effort is.

Comment: Hi Nicholas and welcome to Community Building.  Could you [edit] this to say a little more about what Klout is doing with reputation and social platforms?  (I've not heard of them before.)  Thanks!

Comment: So Klout has been around for a while.  They attempt to merge all of your scores on various social platforms, such as LinkedIn, Twitter, Facebook, etc.  They give you one single number which determines their estimation of your reach and influence.  To you as a consumer, you'll get "perks" from vendors who want you to mention their products online, hopefully.  Lithium bought them a couple years ago and is incorporating the Klout score into their community platform and social monitoring tool.  They're also hoping to expand Klout to products as a centralized review tool like Bazarrevoice.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  I'm (a little) familiar with Lithium but I didn't know Klout.

Comment: Nicholas, edit the  answer itself with the information in your comment.